# Existence of minimizers in a finite dimensional Hilbert space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, maxima-minima

One of the most known theorem of existence of a minimizer of a functional is the following.

${\bf Theorem:}$ Let $H$ be an Hilbert space and $A\subset H$ be a nonempty, bounded, closed and convex subset. If $E:H\to\mathbb R$ is a lower semicontinuous and convex functional, hence $E$ achieves its minimum in $A$, which means that exists $a\in A$ such that $E(a) =\displaystyle\inf_{x\in A} E(x)$.

An interesting variant of that Theorem assures that if $A$ is not bounded, the results remains true if we ask for $E$ to be coercive.

My question is: the above Theorem holds in a Hilbert space (in general, of infinite dimension). What happens if $H$ is finite dimensional, e.g. if $H=\mathbb R$? The result still holds?
If yes, how to prove that?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why would the result not hold if $H$ has finite dimension? That would be written in the theorem conditions. It is sometimes the case that theorems only work in finite dimensions and that this condition is sometimes implicit in the text, but I believe never the reverse. Or perhaps you are just looking for a simpler demonstration when $H$ is finite dimensional? Please clarify.

Comment: By the way, the hypothesis "$A$ is bounded" should be added to the main theorem, otherwise it is false. This is more or less clear when reading "An interesting variant of that Theorem assures that if A is not bounded (...)" but people might read only the first sentence.

Answer (score 1):

In $\mathbb{R}^n$, the demonstration can take advantage of the fact that the bounded closed subsets are the compact subsets. The hypothesis "$A$ is compact" is sufficient: convexity is not needed.

Proof: let $M$ be the minimum of $E$ on $A$ (possibly -$\infty$); we can find points $x_n \in A$ where $E(x_n)$ approaches $M$ as close as we want (in the case of $M=-\infty$, this means $\forall N, \exists x_n \in A, E(x_n)<N$).
As $A$ is compact, we can extract a subsequence $x_{i_n}$ from $x_n$ such that $x_{i_n}$ converges to a point $y$ in $A$.
$E$ being lower semicontinuous, $E(y) \le \lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} E(x_{i_n}) = M$.
So $E(y) \le M$ (which implies $M \ne -\infty$).
As $y \in A$, $E(y) \ge M$. So $E(y) = M$: the minimum is attained by $E$ in $A$.

In the variant where $A$ is not bounded and $E$ is coercive, we use the fact that "$E$ is coercive" is equivalent to $\forall N, \{x \in A, E(x) \le N\}$ is empty or bounded.
Choosing a $N$ such that $B=\{x \in A, E(x) \le N\}$ is non-empty, searching the minimum of $E$ in $A$ is equivalent to searching the minimum of $E$ in $B$.
We take $C$ the closure of $B$. The closure of a bounded subset in a metric space is bounded, so $C$ is bounded.
$C$ being the intersection of all closed subsets that contain $B$, and $A$ being closed and containing $B$, $C$ is included in $A$.
So $C$ is compact, we can apply the first result which shows that $E$ attains its minimum in $C$, and this point is in $A$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Where do you use the convexity of the functional in your proof?

Comment: @user1020 I forgot that condition... Well, in fact convexity of the function is not needed, since in finite dimension we can work with compactness. See for example Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-continuity at the end of Properties: "If $C$ is a compact space" etc.