# Existence of a minimizer in a finite dimensional Hilbert space: unnecessary assumptions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, maxima-minima

I am trying to understand if the following statement holds true:

Let $X$ be a finite dimensional Hilbert space (e.g. $X=\overline{\mathbb{R}}$). Let $I:X\to\mathbb{R}$ be a convex, coercive and lower semicontinuous functional. Let $A\subset X$ be a non empty and closed subset. Then $I$ achieves its minimum, i.e. $\bar{x}\in A$ exists such that $$I(\bar{x}) = \inf_{x\in A} I(x).$$

I know that in a finite dimensional Hilbert space, the continuity of the functional and the compactness of the set $A$ guarantee the existence of a minimizer for $I$.

In the case of the statement above I have lower semicontinuity and coerciveness which imply the boundedness from below of the functional (which clearly does not guarantee the existence of a minimizer).
I was wondering if coercivity + convexity of $I$ together with the only closedness of the set imply that the functional implies the existence of a minimizer. If yes, how to prove it?

In general, do you find that the previous statement contains some unnecessary conditions on $I$ and/or on $A$?

Finally, what about the assumption of convexity for the set $A$ which is required in the case of an infinite dimensional Hilbert space? It seems to disappear in the finite dimensional case (see e.g. [Existence of minimizers in a finite dimensional Hilbert space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4524591/existence-of-minimizers-in-a-finite-dimensional-hilbert-space)).

I hope someone could help me in clarifying these doubts.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: To prove the uniqueness?

Comment: @Neilhawking to prove uniqueness of what?

Comment: of the minimiser.

Comment: Statement is not true, take $J(x) = x$ and $A=\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @mordecaiiwazuki thanks. How to modify the statement to make it true?

Comment: You want the lower level sets of $J(x)$, intersected with $A$, to be compact sets.

Comment: @mordecaiiwazuki so which is the missing assumption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ is a finite-dimensional Hilbert space, $I$ is lower semi-continuous,  $A$ is closed, and $A$ is bounded or $I$ is coercive then you get the existence of a solution. Using the indicator function of $A$ defined by
$$
\delta_A(x):= \begin{cases}0 & \text{ if } x\in A, \\ +\infty & \text{ if } x\not \in A
\end{cases}.
$$
Then $\delta_A$ is lower semicontinuous iff $A$ is closed, $\delta_A$ is coercive iff $A$ is bounded.

And the function $f: X\to \mathbb R\cup \{+\infty\}$ has a global minimum, if $f$ is coercive, lower semicontinuous, and proper (there is $x$ such that $f(x)<+\infty$).

Proof: Let $x_n$ be such that $\lim f(x_n) = \inf_{x\in X} f$. Since $f$ is proper, the infimum is $<+\infty$, since $f$ is coercive, $(x_n)$ is bounded and has a converging subsequence with limit $x$. Due to lower semicontinuity, the limit $x$ is the minimum of $f$.

In infinite-dimensional Hilbert spaces, boundedness does only imply the existence of a *weakly* converging subsequence. Hence, we need $f$ to be weakly lower semicontinuous. Usually this is achieved by assuming $f$ is lower semicontinuous and convex.

Comment: daw, thank you for your answer. I understand correctly that the condition about $A$ the boundedness of $A$ can be replaced with the assumption that $I$ is coercive?

Comment: And that the convexity of the functional is not needed?

Comment: Also, why do you switch from $I$ to $f$? Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: I am more used to minimize $f$ than $I$ ;)

Comment: Convexity of the function is used to get from lower semicontinuity to weakly lower semicontinuity, where usually the first is easier to prove than the second.

Comment: daw, thank you again. So the correct formulation should be: Let $X$
 be a finite dimensional Hilbert space (e.g. $X=\overline{\mathbb{R}})$. Let $I:X\to\mathbb{R}$ be a coercive and lower semicontinuous functional. Let $A\subset X$ be a non empty and closed subset. Then $I$ achieves its minimum, i.e. $\bar{x}\in A$ exists such that $I(\bar{x}) =\inf_{x\in A} I(x)$. Could you please tell me if it is correct then? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Also, if you could please explain a bit more why $A$ bounded can be "replaced" with $I$ coercive, I would be grateful. Many thanks (in any case).

Comment: daw, I am going to accept the answer anyway.

Comment: To your question: yes, you summarized correctly. Coercivity of $I$ or boundedness of $A$ is used to conclude the boundedness of a minimizing sequence. So both assumptions can be used as substitute of each other. In fact, if using the indicator function, then $\delta_A$ is coercive iff $A$ is bounded. One could also combine modifications of both for problems like: $\min e^x$ subject to $x\ge0$.

Comment: Which definition of coercive are you using?

Comment: $f(x)\to \infty$ if $\|x\|\to \infty$.